# Whats easy way to change file permission in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

I don't want to remember codes like 777 all the time . is there any intuitive way to chnage file permission

Suppose i want to have

```
user --rwx
group --rx
others x
```

how can i write this way like

```
chmod ugo +rwxrxx
```

I don't want to keep previous permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't want to keep the old permissions, use this:

```
chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=x FILE
```

Answer (score 6):

You should read man page for `chmod`. There is example:

`chmod u+rwx,g+rx-w,o+x-rw filename`

Comment: He didn't want to keep previous permissions, so `chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=x` is better.

Comment: @Teddy , thanks i like ur solution , i didn't knew i can use =